# How can I stop having IE11 ask me if I want to save or open an .flv file?

Tags: internet-explorer, flv

I am working with 6 different video formats in IE11.  If I try to directly open on of the other 5 (not .flv), either Windows Media Player or QuickTime will open up directly and play the video.  For .flv files though, the browser asks me if I want to save or open the file.  If I click open, the video will play just as with the other 5 formats.  How do I disable this question and always have the video play automatically when clicked?

I am tagging internet-explorer and not internet-explorer-11 because I think the issue may not be specific to that particular version.

Comment: Don't you get a "Always do this" checkbox?

Comment: No.  I get "Do you want to open or save <filename> (<filesize>) from <site>?"  with Open Save and Cancel buttons.

Comment: You need an FLV player that integrates with IE.

Comment: Are your serving the flv files from a web server via some web app or are you opening these locally? i.e., is this a link on a web page, if so please tell us more about your server (apache, IIS, etc.)

Comment: Apache 2.2  I am just testing on localhost right now.  I was first seeing what HTML 5 video tags would give me then I moved on to just clicking on links to see how the videos would be presented.

Comment: That's not the way to present video to visitors. Just serving them a link and letting their browser open it however it wants is no good. Ideally you'd want to use a Flash+Html5 player that can support all platforms and browsers. Something I recommend is [MediaElements](http://mediaelementjs.com/).

Comment: @Kard Nails Ok I'll take a look at that and let you know if that was more what I was after.  I should tell you I have tried video.js and that only allowed me to play 2 of my 6 formats.  My end goal really is to avoid having to do a desktop application (which I already have for the same video formats).

Comment: I expanded my answer below, and if you need more info, just ask. But you should know that you can never avoid everything if you want your site to be user-friendly. You will either have to inconvenience yourself, or your visitors. 6 video formats is about 5 too many. Are you sure you cannot reduce them to one common format? Or is it converting you want to avoid? The problem with so many different formats is that you have no way of knowing whether your visitors will be able to open them. Uploading to Youtube might be another alternative. What are the containers and encoding you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to actually make IE not show the open/download prompt when clicking a linked file, as that is a security measure designed to stop sites from downloading unwanted content on your machine. Just as you can, any user could alter their settings to always open FLV files, but making them do it should not even be considered. So if you want to serve video files to your users, you'd want to use an actual video player, not just a link to the file.

Html5 video tag offer plenty of options and is supported by most modern browsers, especially if you use the [WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) format for your video. [Here](http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-custom-html5-video-player-9134473) is a nice guide on how to make your own design, as all browsers display the html player differently.

The best solution, though, would be to use a player that uses both html5 and flash, so it can support all browsers, including mobile platforms. iOS, we all know, refuses to play flash except through special browsers that download the content you are viewing to their servers and send it to you in a different form. Something like [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) or [MediaElements](http://mediaelementjs.com/) would be perfect.

**The below part is not a valid answer to the OP's question, as he wants to serve FLV video on visitors. It is, however, still usefull to people who wants to configure their own IE browser to always open FLV files by default.**

Save the FLV file instead of opening it, then click "View Downloads". Right click on the file and uncheck "Always ask before opening this type of file". From now on, all FLV files should open by default.

Comment: This is a process then that anyone who accesses that site has to go through?  It does work, but I was hoping for a more out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Those are security and personal settings. While you may add MIME types to, say, force a certain file to always download, you cannot remove the IE (or any other browser) open/download prompt. Those are user end settings.

Comment: The "Always ask before opening this type of file" checkbox does not appear to be available in the downloads list on IE11, or its function is not as readily accessible anymore. Do you know how to enable this option for certain file types on IE11?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this happened to me because the Windows Explorer file type association had been changed to use IE as the default program.  To fix, right-click on any .flv file in Windows Explorer, select "open with", Choose Another App, and then reset the default to Windows Media Player or your preferred app.

[image]